# How to duplicate a GitHub Codespace for use as a development template?

Tags: github, github-codespaces

I have a Codespace with a bunch of development tools installed.

I'd like to use this Codespace as a template so that I can start new projects from there.

I can create a Dockerfile that installs the tooling, and then build a new Codespace from that.

But is there a way I can just create a new Codespace from an existing one?

Comment: Agreed. Please help